# CasperJS Angular Button not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click through this website's login section using Casper. The website uses Angular to validate form responses. When I fill in the "Enter Username" input and click "Login" button, the screenshot that I get shows the "Login" button transform to "Checking" text and remains like that.

Here is my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
   //enter the username

   this.evaluate(fillUserName,username);
   console.log("username entered")
      this.then(function() {

      //without this wait function, no click action occurs 
         this.wait(2000, function() {
            console.log("clicking on the login")
            this.click('#submit-username')
         });
     });
 });
```

Like I mentioned in the code, without the wait() no click action even occurs.

Here is the code from the "Login" button that I am trying to click:

```
<button ng-click="CheckUser(false)" type="submit" class="btn 
btn-success" ng-class="{'btn-success': 
(Login.ErrorMessage.length == 0), 'btn-danger': 
(Login.ErrorMessage.length > 0)}" id="submit-username" data- 
loading-text="Checking..." data-vis-is-button- 
disabled="EnabledState">Log In</button>
```

How can I click on the button?